# Using a Python script to store entities in GAE cloud datastore automatically

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, csv

I have written a Python script that scrapes our university's HTML page for all the degree information we need. It produces a `.csv` file of all the data. The data from the `.csv` files is then uploaded to the datastore using methods in our API.

It's a particularly dull process. Since we can only make requests that are under one minute, we need to break up the `.csv` file into many different bits. Obviously, this is not cool.

We initially envisioned a database that would take our python script and update/populate itself every year with all new degree information. A python script running alongside a GAE cloud datastore that was coded in Java.

Is it possible to do this? Can we get the database to update itself?

If so, is it possible that we can make it happen both manually and automatically?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: have a look at tasks which have a 10 minute time out or backend modules that have even longer limits.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you are wanting to take the csv file you create using one Python script, and then parse it with another program and upload that data to the Datastore so its accessible for other things.

There are a couple options I see:

1. Use Pull Queues. Setup an Appengine project that hosts a RESTful service that your current Python script can upload the CSV file to and the App processes/puts it into the Datastore.
2. Build an App with a cron job that checks a specific location for new CSV files, have the original Python script (or manually) place the CSV file into that certain folder, and consume it. The App could also have a page where you can manually upload a CSV file, which would give you your automatic and manual options.

The specifics of each one and how you build them would be up to you of course.

Comment: So as far as you can see there is no way we get the database to do this automatically?

Comment: I think you have to go through an appengine project to work with a Datastore. If you want your DB to automagically sync with the datastore, the first option I described above would be best - have the project expose some APIs that your DB to could hook into, or something to that affect. Again, I'm no expert, but that's what I would suggest.

As an aside, what are you doing with the data after it has been placed into a Datastore? Are you processing it or just using it to show to end users/run queries against?